# Django language switch not working

Tags: django, django-models, internationalization, django-templates, django-views

I would like to translate URL prefix and also URL slug using django-modeltranslation where slug is saved inside database table. After switching the language i would like to stay on the same page and just change the language. I'm using form language switcher as described here:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#the-set-language-redirect-view

Problem is that the language is just switching on homepage. The other pages are just refreshed without language and URL change.

Is there any way how can i get current url in other language?

In root project urls.py i have following:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
   # Examples:
   (r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
   url(r'^$', 'portfolio.views.home', name='home'),
   # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
   url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns('',
    url(_(r'^projects/'), include('projects.urls', namespace='projects')),
)
```

in app called projects i have urls :

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', all_projects, name='projects'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', project_detail, name='project_detail'),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is not a copy-paste-problem you're missing `url` function name in your main `urls.py`. Change line 3 of your provided code above to:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
   ...
   # The following line need to be changed from
   # (r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
   # to
   url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
   ...
)
```